# Не получается установить psycopg2 | python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psycopg2, python-3.12

Я скачал python 3.12, хотел скачать psycopg2 но произошла ошибка (хотя это библиотека нормально установилась на прошлой версии python)

Ошибка:

```
pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.9.tar.gz (384 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
     
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
     
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
     
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
     
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
     
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
     
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дождаться исправлений в пакете psycopg2. Пока как вариант использовать Python 3.11
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1628

Comment: Ну да, ну да. Так сейчас со многими библиотеками на 12 питоне.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо